# OnReceive is never called after register BroadCast receiver of MainActivity from another class

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

**PROBLEM:** I'm trying to register a `BroadcastReceiver` for my `MapsActivity` from  a method (`scanWifiSignal()`)of an object (`m`)  instance of  another class (`wifiConnectivity`) which is instantiated in a `LocationUpdate` class method (`checkLocationSettings`). The problem is that `OnReceive` callback is never called. 
if I move the code of the `BroadcastReceiver` and the callback `OnReceive` declarations into maps activity class the  everything works fine.
Below the code simplified.

**QUESTION:**  I'm ask you to help me to spot the problem in the code below. I think is something related with the scope of`wifiScanReceiver` but I'm not sure. Thanks for your help.

**MapsActivity**

```
 public class  extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    public BroadcastReceiver wifiScanReceiver;
    private WifiManager wifiManager;
    private final LocationUpdate locationUpdate= new LocationUpdate(MapsActivity.this);



 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        // If location permission is granted initialize Map
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            mapSync();

        } else {    

                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION);    
        }    
    }

 @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;    

        // Check if localization permission is granted
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);                

            // If wifi is the active connection, enable settings to get location updates and start wifi signal scan
            if(wifi.checkWifiConnection()){

                // Check if location settings are appropriated for the location request
                locationUpdate.checkLocationSettings(mLocationRequest,REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS, mFusedLocationClient,mLocationCallback,mMap);  


            } else {

                // Check if location settings are appropriated for the location request
                locationUpdate.checkLocationSettings(mLocationRequest,REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS,mFusedLocationClient,mLocationCallback,mMap);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"no wifi, check tipo connessione attuale", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }


        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION);
            }
        }
    }
```

**wifiConnectivity**

```
 public class wifiConnectivity {

        private MapsActivity mapsActivity;
        private BroadcastReceiver wifiScanReceiver;                
        private Context context;

        public wifiConnectivity(MapsActivity mapsActivity)
        {
              this.mapsActivity = mapsActivity;
                    this.context = mapsActivity.getApplicationContext();
                }


       public void scanWifiSignal(){

              final WifiManager wifiManager;            
              wifiManager = mapsActivity.getWifiManager();            
              wifiScanReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

              @Override
              public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                     mapsActivity.setLocalMaxSignalStrength(0);            
                    ist<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();

                            //public void handleWifiScanResults()
                            for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {

                                ScanResult el = results.get(i);

                                // Get signal level as a number from 0 to n-1
                                int signalLevel = wifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(el.level, 5);

                                // If signal level value is greater than the registered max, update the max value.
                                if (signalLevel >= mapsActivity.getLocalMaxSignalStrength()){
                                    mapsActivity.setLocalMaxSignalStrength(signalLevel);
                                }

                                Toast.makeText(mapsActivity.getApplicationContext(), "SSID:" + el.SSID + "frequency" + el.frequency + "lev:" + signalLevel, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        }
                    };
                    mapsActivity.setWifiScanReceiver(wifiScanReceiver);
                   this.context.registerReceiver(wifiScanReceiver, new IntentFilter(wifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));

                   mapsActivity.setReceivingWifiScanResults(true);

                }
```

**LocationUpdate**

```
   public class LocationUpdate {
        private MapsActivity mapsActivity;
        private wifiConnectivity m ;




     public LocationUpdate(MapsActivity mapsActivity)
     {
            this.mapsActivity=mapsActivity;
     }
             public void checkLocationSettings(final LocationRequest mLocationRequest, final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS,  final FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient, final LocationCallback mLocationCallback, final GoogleMap mMap) {


                // Get and check location services settings
                LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                        .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest)
                        .setAlwaysShow(true);


                SettingsClient client = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(mapsActivity);
                Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());

                task.addOnSuccessListener(mapsActivity, new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {

                        // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize
                        // location requests here
                        LocationUpdate locationUpdate = new LocationUpdate(mapsActivity);

                        locationUpdate.getLastKnownLocation(mFusedLocationClient);
                        locationUpdate.startLocationUpdates(mFusedLocationClient, mLocationCallback, mLocationRequest);

                        m=new wifiConnectivity(mapsActivity);
                        m.scanWifiSignal();


                    }
                });
                                    this.context = mapsActivity.getApplicationContext();
                        }
```

Comment: private final LocationUpdate locationUpdate= new LocationUpdate(MapsActivity.this); is outside onCreate

Comment: What happens if you use registerReceiver() with mapsActivity instead of with the application context?

Comment: @Raghunandan I've tried to move locationUpdate inside onCreate but nothing changes.

Comment: @0X0nosugar I've tried to use MapsActivity instead of application context and it didn't affected the behaviour. Still onReceive never called.

Comment: @Maicake i said that cause your context is tied to activity lifecycle. hence context may be null. Do you see any crashes?

Comment: No crash but I've just noticed thath happens the following: if I put the application onPause, for example pressing home button and I leave the app in pause for about 2-3' when I resume the app it receives the wifi scan result (but just once).